# Porting java interface to IDL

Tags: java, interface, corba, idl

I have a java RMI app that I want to port to using CORBA. To do that, I have to change the remote interface definition from java to IDL but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

At the moment one of the methods in the java interface has a parameter that is not a predefined datatype (like string, int etc) but one that I defined myself. In the java interface you would define it like that:

```
public int doSomething(MyObject o);
```

In the RMI implementation passing of the object is made possible because both the client and server have the definition of class MyObject on their build path.

So I am wondering if it would work if I put the MyObject files on both client and server and then change the method definition in IDL to something like this:

```
long doSomething(in MyObject o);
```

Or do I need to define this class and its methods somehow also in the IDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define MyObject in your idl module well. It's not sufficient to have the class defined in the build path for both client and server.

Comment: nah you will just define an interface in your idl module with MyObject will then implement and your method signatures become doSomething(MyInterface ) etc...

Comment: in this MyInterface do I need to define only the methods of the object that are used on server or all methods? Also do I have to make this object class implement this interface in java?

Comment: What you expose in your interface is a design decision, but at a minimum you need everything that class receiving the implementation requires. Unless you cast it to MyObject and then you get everything that MyObject exposes.
And yes you will have to make Myobject implement MyInterface

Comment: no problems :), I am curious to know why you are going from RMI to CORBA? I actually made the opposite transition (CORBA to RMI) for many reasons, more developers familiar with RMI, performance, it's an all java system so it reduces the advantages of CORBA as well. What is the reason that made you move the other way (interfacing with languages other than java?)

Comment: Yes, interfacing with other languages also.

Answer (score 3):

*rmic -idl* will do that for you. See the tools documentation.

Comment: Yea, it looks like that would have been the easy way. Got the idl done manually already, though.